# Facebook Insight data not appearing for website

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I have recently been looking into adding Facebook Insights into one of our client's websites (www.mcvuk.com). I've created an app to associate with this and added the necessary Facebook meta tags to my site which reference the app id.

I was, until today, having issues adding the app domain information to https://developers.facebook.com/apps but have added this information in today.

My question is how long does it take before you will start to see results filter through for the site and is there any way of checking that everything has been set up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a matter of time, it might be a matter of how many 'likes' the app or page has.  At least for pages, it tells you "Once 30 people like your Page, you'll get access to insights about your activity."

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting point.

It all depends on which metrics (results) you're after and how much traffic your app gets.

Additionally, you might want to look at facebook documentation for the metrics (results) you're looking for -- some of them are available monthly or weekly, others are a lifetime aggregate, and some are daily.

The easiest way to test would be to ask some of your friends to do whatever it is you want to test (comment on a post, link to a page, etc.).

I hope that answers some of your questions.